# How to use update and select form the same table ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table :

```
`id`      `activity_time`
 1    0000-00-00 00:00:00
 2    2015-06-1 12:12:12
 3    0000-00-00 00:00:00
 4    0000-00-00 00:00:00
 5    2015-06-2 13:13:13
```

I want to update every row with date "0000-00-00 00:00:00" and set it to the first next non "0000-00-00 00:00:00" row.

so id #1 will be set to `2015-06-1 12:12:12`.

and #3 , #4 will be set to `2015-06-2 13:13:13`.

I am trying to run this query :

```
UPDATE 
      table1
      SET activity_time =
          (
             SELECT activity_time FROM table1 as t2
             where
             t2.activity_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
             AND
             t2.id > table1.id
             ORDER BY Id ASC
             limit 1
          )
      WHERE activity_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

but I go this error :

```
You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can use a `join` for this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN
       (SELECT t1.*,
               (SELECT t1b.activity_time
                FROM table1 t1b
                WHERE t1b.activity_time <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND
                      t1b.id > t1.id
                ORDER BY t1b.id ASC
                LIMIT 1
               ) as next_activity_time
        FROM table1 t1a
        WHERE t1a.activity_time <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      ) tnxt
      ON tnxt.id = t1.id
      SET t1.activity_time = tnxt.next_activity_time
      WHERE t1.activity_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

The basic idea is to rewrite your query as a `SELECT` to get the values you want.  Then `join` this back to your query to get the information for the update.

Comment: as usual, great answer (kill semi-c in 2nd to last line)